# Non-standard usage of wait notify in concurrent Java programs

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, wait, notify

I am very familiar with how the `wait() / notify()` signaling scheme works in Java. However, I realized that the few usage patterns I've seen are variants of the [Producer / Consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) scheme, or implementation of a [Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29). Also I have seen implementations of some well-known concurrent problems, such as the *Dining Philosophers* using wait/notify, but apparently for didactic purposes.

Moreover, all schemes followed the well-behaved recommendation of always invoking `wait()` inside a loop, and only alter some shared variable after passing the loop, like the following code:

```
synchronized(mon) {

   // #CP1 - Do not change variables here

   while !(mycondition) {
      try{
         // #CP2 Do not change variables here
         mon.wait();
      } catch(catch (InterruptedException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
   }

   // Condition satisfied - Now you can change!      
   makeOperation();

   // Tell others that you're done and exit
   mon.notifyAll();
}
```

My questions is: are there other patterns of usage of `wait() / notify()` signaling than the ones I cited? Have you ever used it in an non-orthodox way? Why? Here are some more concrete questions to help:

1. Have you ever seen implementation where a shared variable is altered before exiting the loop? In my example, would there be a reason to assign something in the control points `#CP1` and `#CP2`?
2. Is there some case where you chose to use `notify()`instead of `notifyAll()`? Though the possible performance gain, where you very sure about this wouldn't cause some dead-lock? Why?
3. Is there some complex scenario, where the waiting condition `mycondition` depends on more than 1 thread, e.g., `mycondition= a_ready && b_ready && c_ready`?

Comment: I would argue that in modern times the use of `wait` and `notify` **is** the non-standard way of controlling threads. It can be argued that there is nothing that can be done with them that cannot be done with `java.util.concurrent` tools and without the edge effects.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : I agree that `wait` and `notify` are non-standard since `java.util.concurrent`. But is there someone using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`, which is sort of a high-level replacement for `wait/notify`? If so, the question still holds.

Comment: I would think restricting yourself to `Condition` is invalid. Producer/Consumer architecture can now be done perfectly with various `BlockingQueue` classes handling one-to-many, many-to-one and one-to-one data flow. Beyond that you can move into `CyclicBarrier`, atomics and even `ForkJoinPool` to achieve almost anything. You also get a variety other goodies such as `Futures` and `ThreadPool`s. Trying to compare  the old `wait/notify` with the richness of `j.u.concurrent` is comparing chalk and cheese.

Comment: Indeed you have a point about the facilities provided by `j.u.current`.

Answer (score 1):

1. sure.  one example would be that at #CP1 you could keep a "waiting list".  i'm not sure i can think of shared state you might be altering at #CP2 as generally the while loop is only there in the case of "spurious" wakeups (i.e. you were woken up but really shouldn't have been).  also, your handling of InterruptedException is generally a bad idea, as it doesn't allow the thread to be shutdown (a spurious wakeup is *different* from getting InterruptedException).
2. If you know that only one waiter will be proceeding, you can use notify instead of notifyAll.  this can be much more efficient if there are large number of waiting threads.  *however*, there are some caveats when using notify that you need to be very careful about.  a waiter could be notified *and* interrupted, so your handling of InterruptedException needs to re-notify (so the notification doesn't get lost).  this means that even if you only intend a single waiter to be awoken, you need to correctly handle the case that more than one could be awoken.  in general, you have to make sure that your code correctly causes another thread to proceed, or you could end up in a deadlock situation.
3. sure.  you could have one flag which indicates that a given thread should proceed and a separate one which indicates that all threads should abort (system shutdown or algorithm abort).